# Aptana Studio 3 error while loading

Tags: installation, aptana, aptana3, installation-package

I am receiving an error message while trying to load Aptana Studio 3 in an ubuntu 16.04 LTS installation.

In the following url you can read the errors according to the following: log file.
[log_file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cjnddb86klzbzzp/1507200912588.log?dl=0)

I have oracle-java9 installed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved.
AptanaStudio3 (v3.6.1) is not compatible with Oracle-Java9.

After installing Oracle-Java8 the app is running normally.